# R function early report execution status

Tags: r, function, return, plumber

I am working on an API that will initialize, via POST method, a function (e.g. irrigation_function) that read's raster maps and perform irrigation requirements calculations. The process may take several minutes, so before the final result, I want to be able to return a fast report when I recieve the POST request e.g.:

```
{
 "field_id": "oasdghosad-sdfas-12124",
 "date-time": "2022-06-10T10:30:0983Z",
 "status": "PREPARING"
}
```

I understand that I can use only one return() within the irrigation_function, located at the end or otherwise the function execution will be halted. So how can I retrive the early report without stopping the execution of the function?

Comment: An HTTP response has a header that tells the receiver how many bytes the response will be and that has to do at the beginning of the response. That makes it hard to send a response until you have all parts calculated. And most libraries that consume responses wait until the response is complete before parsing it. It doesn't seem compatible with the HTTP protocol to have multiple responses for the same request

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I solved the problem by moving a certain part of my code to another script which I trigger before the function return() to run aychronous via 'system("Rscript path_to_your_script/some_script.R",wait = FALSE)'